# Editing a row in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In my RAdGrid that I am using there's this edit button to edit a Question in the list. When I click on edit, it is ALWAYS the
first row data that is fetched from Ques table..like it is always the first ques that gets filled when Edit button is clicked
no matter what question's edit button I click. I am using Telerik's RADgrid so cannot pass CommandArgument to Edit button..what's wrong ??

```
            if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
            {
                Common com = new Common();
                Int32 ID = Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["QuesID"].ToString());

                Response.Redirect(http://localhost/myweb/ + "editques/" + "QuesID/" + QuesID + "/" + PID);
            }

   ALTER PROC [Admin].[sp_Ques]    
(
 @QuesID bigint =null 
 )
AS
BEGIN
........
END
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be here:        obj.QuesID = ID;
        DataSet dsQues = obj.getQues();
But you didnt cover that code... 1. Does it get the right ID? If the id is right, does it get the right data record?

Comment: @Cine :: Thats what I said above..When I debugged, its getting the ID alright...plz check the text in bold italics at the end of the ques, you will know what problem I am having

Comment: In that case, that is the code you want to be showing us...

Comment: @Cine:: I have added the code..Plz help..thnx

Comment: Why is it always fetching the first row when editting? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending any parameters to your `[Admin].[sp_Ques]` and since it has a default null value, you dont get any error message about it either