# Why this error:: There is no row at position 0.?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
DataSet dsQues = obj.getQues();
txtQues.Text = dsQues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Ques"].ToString(); //error here
```

Comment: Well, you haven't posted `getFAQ()` which makes it hard to say...

Comment: You should update the text in your original question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301149) rather than posting another one...

Comment: @Jon :: Have corrected the mistake in my code..theer's no getFAq..its getQues() only

Comment: @Graham:: I have changed my SP! :( besides no one wud answer there and I need help bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you are not setting the value of @QuesID parameter in your code. And in the database there is no row having QuesID as NULL.

Answer (score 2):

becoz

```
dsFAQ.Tables[0].Rows is a empty collection , please check your SP is returning some rows or not
```

Answer (score 1):

Or that there is no column "FAQs".

Answer (score 1):

Please check that your obj.getFAQ() is returning values.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have an empty DataSet (or that you're referencing an empty table in the DataSet).

I'm guessing the root cause is that the Stored Procedure backing you calls is returning zero rows. You're not passing any parameters to the Procedure, so you could try running this query by hand and seeing how many rows come back:

```
SELECT * FROM Admin.Ques WHERE QuesID = NULL
```

Comment: but why ? Is my Sp wrong or what? what's wrong anyway? Could u plz check my earlier code and tell me if that Sp was correct ?? :/

Comment: @Serenity - I updated my answer...you're not passing any parameters to the stored procedure so the query in my answer is what is being executed. I'm guessing that is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to execute in debug mode with a break point at the problematic line and try to see what is in your DataSet.. Probably  IT is empty!

Comment: Well apparently its empty so the error. i am asking why is it empty? What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Try to execute your stored procedure in a SQLCommandPrompt and see what is the result -- Yes HE is not the correct word!! Sorry :-)